# Windows 10 unresponsive in screensaver mode - how can I figure out what process or app was taking all its CPU?

Tags: windows-10, cpu

My windows 10 Dell machine is stuck on screensaver screen. I can press keyboard buttons (keyboard lights work) and I can click mouse but it seems to be processing something in the background and does not bring up the login screen.

How can I find out what process or app was taking up all its CPU at that time after a reboot?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tool to monitor and log processes such as Sysinternals' [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/process-monitor/?license=free&platform=windows). To minimize the length of the log file, start the monitor and then go to the lock screen.

You might check first for the three most-likely culprits:

- A screen-saver that monopolizes time, e.g. a [coin miner](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/intelligence/coinminer-malware) or just graphics-intensive on a slow CPU.
- Malware such as [coin miners](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/intelligence/coinminer-malware).
- Legitimate Windows processes such as Search (Cortana) Indexing, automatic cleanup and disk optimization.

Comment: Or BOINC doing some computing